# Azure WebJobs vs Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-webjobs, quartz.net, background-service

If I have a **`WebJob`** project in my application and set the CRON expression in Azure Cloud like in the photo below then why would I need the package **`Quartz.NET`**?
The WebJob project has a class inheriting BackgroundService and calls AddHostedService.

[image]

#### My findings

**1. Possible disadvantage of Quartz.NET**
a. Can I use Quartz.NET with Azure Storage Queue, Tables, etc.? If not, this would be a disadvantage.
b. Quartz.NET seems focused only on time scheduling. If I want a background task firing not from a time trigger, then Quartz.NET has no use?

**2. Possible advantage of Quartz.NET**
I know you can create multiple jobs with Quartz. In a simple WebJob I would have to repetitively add HostedService for each one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < workerConfiguration.WorkerCount; i++)
{
   services.AddHostedService<BackgroundTaskService>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a WebJob project in your application and your use case is to set the CRON expression in Azure Cloud, then you might not need the package Quartz_.NET and the `BackgroundService`  class is a part of the .NET Core framework and provides a way to run background tasks in a hosted service.

> b. Quartz.NET seems focused only on time scheduling. If I want a background task firing not from a time trigger, then Quartz.NET has no use?

- Quartz_.NET can be used to schedule background tasks that are not triggered by time. It can be triggered and scheduled by time according to this Blog- [Using Quartz.NET with ASP.NET Core and worker services (andrewlock.net](https://andrewlock.net/using-quartz-net-with-asp-net-core-and-worker-services/).

> a. Can I use Quartz.NET with Azure Storage Queue, Tables, etc.? If not, this would be a disadvantage.

- Quartz_.NET provides a way to integrate with different job stores, including Azure Storage. You can use the  `Quartz.Plugins.AzureTable.AdoJobStore`  package to store job data in Azure Table Storage, As-well-as `Quartz.Plugins.AzureQueue.AdoJobStore`  package can use to store job data in [Azure Storage Queue](https://code-maze.com/azure-webjobs-in-app-service/).

Use  `IScheduler.ScheduleJob`  method to schedule multiple jobs with different triggers.

Here’s an example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Quartz;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class QuartzHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;

    public QuartzHostedService(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);

        // Schedule Job1 every 5 minutes
        var job1 = JobBuilder.Create<Job1>()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .Build();

        var trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?")
            .Build();

        await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1, cancellationToken);

        // Schedule Job2 every 10 minutes
        var job2 = JobBuilder.Create<Job2>()
            .WithIdentity("job2", "group1")
            .Build();

        var trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger2", "group1")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/10 * * * ?")
            .Build();

        await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job2, trigger2, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _scheduler.Shutdown(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```